# Why are images in TabView cropped in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm creating a TabView in SwiftUI that uses a vertical scrolling mechanism to display images. However, the images are cropped on the sides with the code I'm using, and I'm looking for an uncropped look. Interestingly, they only become cropped when running on an iPad in landscape mode. Would anyone be able to help? Thanks!

```swift
TabView {
   ForEach(courses, id: \.self) { course in
       NavigationLink {
           iPadInfoView(event: course)
       } label: {
           ZStack {
             Image("event_img")
                .resizable()
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                .scaledToFit()
             VStack {
                Text(course.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .font(.system(size: 28))
                Text(course.location ?? "No Location")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding([.top])
                Text(course.startDate, style: .time)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .italic()
         }
       }
     }
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(270))
  }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
    .navigationTitle("Today")
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx Hi, thanks for your comment! I'm new to SO, so would you be able to identify something else I should include? This is really all I have for this part.

Comment: Did you read the link?